# Unordered associative containers, best choice

Tags: c++, stl, set

Which option is the best way to use an unordered_set for an efficient look up,

- Boost(I guess this is the way to go, since these will be in the next standard)
- Sgi STL
- STLPort

I am asking because these three are mentioned in Effective STL by Scott Meyers but the book is a bit old.

Comment: `unordered_set` is standard in C++11, you don't need anything else.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to work with a pre-C++11 compiler, use boost:

- it's almost everywhere,
- it's a header library,
- it's modular,
- it's compliant with all the standards, so totally compatible with the standard library.

Comment: Ok, I got a look up in boost documentation, now what I would like to do is to find the index of an element in an unordered_set however there are no subtraction operators for unordered_set iterators, how may I find the index, any ideas?

Comment: woah, why do you want to index? The set is _unordered_, so it should be meaningless. If you want to save the location temporarily, use the iterator (just don't trust it if you do anything with the set)

Comment: well unfortunately, I need to because I use these indices later on to select some elements that I want

Comment: the iterator is basically a pointer to an element in the container. But as I mentioned, the standard makes no promises about what happens to these if the container is modified, so it's not very safe to hold on to them for long. If you want a robust index, by definition your set must be ordered.

Comment: right, but the container does not change, these containers are a property of an input to the program but std::distance does the job

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're doing: `unordered_set` is typically O(1) lookup, so looking up a list of k keys is going to be O(k). On the other hand, getting these elements by looping over the iterators and then walking down the iterators is going to be O(n*k). Additionally, std::distance is going to be O(n). Why not just save the keys?